# django connections shared across threads causes ora-01000 maximum open cursors exeeded

Tags: python, django, multithreading, oracle, orm

I want to stop executing SQL statement if it takes too long to run.

To achieve this I hacked `django.core.db.backends.oracle.base`. In `FormatStylePlaceholderCursor.execute` and  `executemany` instead of:

```
return self.cursor.execute(TIMEOUT, query, self._param_generator(params))
```

I do:

```
return timelimited(TIMEOUT, self.cursor.execute, query, self._param_generator(params))
```

And `timelimited` is a function from this recipe: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576780-timeout-for-nearly-any-callable/. It wraps a function (i.e. `cursor.execute`) in separate thread and waits `TIMEOUT`. If function doesn't return the thread is stopped.

With this modification the application I'm running is throwing ora-01000 maximum cursors exceeded after some short period of time. I'm wandering why wrapping `cursor.execute` is causing this problem, how to fix it and what are other available solution to this problem.

Comment: What does it mean "killed"? Can you control the killing procedure? Why do you need a timeout? Oracle, when parsing a query, creates a "program" which gets executed. This remains present in Oracle's memory until either the query is closed or database connection is closed.

Comment: probably [this thread](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?23463-How-to-set-query-timeout-in-DB/page2) can be helpful

Comment: @Ivan - I mean calling thread.stop(). I need a timeout because this will be connection to the cache database. If cache database is not available or takes long to respond I don't wont to wait for ages. I want to cancel execution and go to the main database instead.

Comment: @alko - this actually isn't helpful. Please not I'm trying to protect from the case when connection is broken - something happened in the middle of otherwise short query, so this needs to be handled on the client side.

Comment: btw, what python (jython/cpython/pypy and version) are you using?

Comment: I asked, as there is a related jython bug. Can you check (for example with `threading.enumerate()`) how many (at moment error occurs) invoked via your script threads are running? I suspect each thread opens cursors and it is not closed, but cant test right now (don't have appropriate env now)

Comment: other option is that if you don't properly terminate your threads, nor `__del__` neither `close` are not executed for cursors, and they are never closed, that is oracle threats them as open for your connection. you should ensure that open cursors are closed with your script despite how you terminate it. again, can't test

Comment: @alko Yes - I clearly understand that there is resource leak and there is now way to really kill python thread. But I'm just wandering what would be a good solution to this problem instead of using threads.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Django nor Python. I can tell you what OCI drivers offer to users.

- You must close the query handle - or whatever is it's name in Python. Otherwise you're leaking resources on database side
- If the query is still active, you can interrupt it using OCIBreak call. This one is thread safe, and can be called from any thread, regardless what background thread is doing with the connection
- Try to check, whether Python drivers for Oracle do allow you to call OCIBreak and OCIReset

[This](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/connection.html#Connection.cancel) is what you need. `Connection.cancel()`

Comment: Honestly I don't this is something what I need. Let me explain (just four lines of code, sorry for lack of formatting in comments):
import cx_Oracle as db \n
conn = db.connect(connect_string) \n
#HERE UNPLUG YOUR ETHERNET CABLE \n
conn.ping() # will hang forever \n

Comment: Ok, in this case you're facing DCD (dead connection detection) issues. There were written many articles about that and also Oracle made several recommendations. The "best" approach is to put strange clause `(ENABLE=BROKEN)` into `tnsnames.ora` entry. This make Oracle use TCPKeepAlive on network connection. The you will need root privs. to tune several kernel level parameters related to TCPKeepAlive. The trick is that DCD is handled by Linux kernel in this case - and this approach really works.

Comment: `Connection.cancel()` interrupts "thread" execution on DB server side. Which can be the fastest way how to return a connection into the pool. Of course this works only when you do not have any network issues.